# Why did my blender crash when I use my python scriping to import a lot of x3d files?

Tags: python, rendering, objects, export, import

I use the code to import x3d files and render them and export png. If I run this code, I can only get one picture, then the blender crashed. So it means that my code only imported one x3d file, rendered it and exported a png then when it imported the second x3d file, blender shut down. I don't know why.

```
import bpy 
import os 

D = bpy.data

# folder path to save rendered image
in_dir = "D:\\01\\in\\"
lst = os.listdir(in_dir)

# folder path for importing data files
in_dir_x3d = "D:\\01\\x3d\\"
lst_x3d = os.listdir(in_dir_x3d)

# folder path to save rendered animation
out_dir = "D:\\01\\out\\test.avi"

# Filter file list by valid file types.
candidates = []
candidates_name = []
c = 0
for item in lst_x3d:
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(lst_x3d[c])
    if fileExtension == ".x3d":
        candidates.append(item)
        candidates_name.append(fileName)
    c = c + 1
file = [{"name":i} for i in candidates]   
n = len(file)

# To import x3d in batches
for i in range (0,n):
    bpy.ops.import_scene.x3d(filepath="D:\\01\\X3D\\"+candidates[i], 
axis_forward='Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.x3d")
    # deselect all
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # selection
    D.objects['Shape_LineSet'].select = True
    D.curves['Shape_LineSet'].bevel_depth = 0.001
    # deselect all
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # selection
    bpy.data.objects['DirectLight'].select = True

    # remove it
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    #delete materials
    for block in bpy.data.materials:
        #print(block)
        if block != bpy.data.materials['water']:
            D.materials.remove(block)




    D.objects['Shape_IndexedFaceSet.019'].material_slots[0].material = D.materials['water']
    D.objects['Shape_IndexedFaceSet'].material_slots[0].material = D.materials['water']

    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = 'D://01//out//%02d'%(i)    #set save filepath
    bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )    #render and save
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            obj.select = True
        else:
            obj.select = False
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if obj.type == 'CURVE':
            obj.select = True
        else:
            obj.select = False
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    for block in bpy.data.meshes:
        if block.users == 0:
            bpy.data.meshes.remove(block)

    for block in bpy.data.materials:
        if block.users == 0:
            bpy.data.materials.remove(block)

    for block in bpy.data.textures:
        if block.users == 0:
            bpy.data.textures.remove(block)

    for block in bpy.data.images:
        if block.users == 0:
            bpy.data.images.remove(block)
```

Comment: There is no need to put your body text in an h1. What error message did you get in the console?

Comment: "Saved ''D:\01\out\00.png Time:00:45.33(Saving 00:00.39)". I think this word means it rendered and saved the first picture  succcessfully. But then it displays that "Error :EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION". Then the console and blender vanished together.  @David

Comment: Going by the indenting in script above it will only render once?? Is it mis-pasted?

Comment: @batFINGER when it will import the second x3d file, blender vanished.

Comment: Please check whether the code above matches your original script. The render operator in script above will only be called once (it has zero indent) , after you have imported all x3d objects in the loop.    (to format code  for bse, select it after pasting  and hit the code {} button or ctrl-K)

Comment: @batFINGER  Thanks. My original code is right. Here it is a layout problem. I have edit it again.